# Android: How to determine which Wi-Fi network is connected

Tags: android, connection, wifi

I know how to determine if a wi-fi connection is the active connection.  However, can someone tell how to determine which wi-fi network is the current active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `WifiManager.getConnectionInfo()`. This returns a `WifiInfo` object which contains all the info you need about the active wifi connection; in particular, `WifiInfo.getSSID()` will give you the SSID.

Comment: I see nothing in the returned information that determines which network is connected.  Only generic information.  I need the SSID of the currently connected network.

Comment: The returned WifiInfo object only pertains to the currently connected network. Call `WifiInfo.getSSID()` for the SSID.

Answer (score 1):

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String BSSID=wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getBSSID();
```

Comment: the question has been already an answer. You shoul vote up the correct answre instead of post it again.

Comment: Sorry blackbelt, but when I start to write this answer, was diferent. After I answer, it was edited.